# Making an odd shaped table

Tags: tables, multicol, multirow

I'm trying to make a table that looks like this:

```
               +--------------+
               |   Class 1    |
               +--------------+
               |   A  |   B   |
+---------+----+------+-------+
|         | C  |   a  |   b   |
| Class 2 +----+------+-------+
|         | D  |   c  |   d   |
+---------+----+------+-------+
```

There are many things wrong with my code. First is the way that the word span appears in front of the `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{\textbf{Class 1}}}` entry (which doesn't span the line). Second the line between C and D goes all the way through class 2. I don't know how to get rid of the lines in the top right. It's a real mess, what am I doing wrong? Apologies for the not-very specific question.

```
\begin{tabular}{|r|c||c|c|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{\textbf{Class 1}}} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & A & B \\
  \multirow{2}{*}{{\textbf{Class 2}}}
    & C & a & b \\
  \hline
    & D & c & d \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I stole most of the answer from [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) , but I think this is what you want

```
\begin{tabular}{rc|c|c|}
\cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{\textbf{Class 1}}} \\
\cline{3-4}
& & A & B \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{{\textbf{Class 2}}}}& C & a & b \\
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}& D & c & d \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 9):

If you are typesetting sort of Cayley table, then I think the approach by *Rick de Groot* is good. If it's more a text table, you might use the package `booktabs` to enhance the look your table a little, omitting the verical lines and adding some vertical space:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rccc}
\toprule
  & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{{\textbf{Class 1}}}
\\\cmidrule{3-4}
  & & A & B
\\\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
  \textbf{Class 2}
    & C & a & b
\\\cmidrule{2-4}
    & D & c & d
\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Variant two:** As *Jake* pointed out, this solution cannot be used with the `multirow` package to center `Class 2`. More tweaking using `calc` package can be done:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rccc}
\toprule
  & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{{\textbf{Class 1}}}
\\\cmidrule{3-4}
  & & A & B
\\\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
  \begingroup\makeatletter
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{\totalheightof{\strut}}
  \smash{\raisebox{-0.5\@tempdima-0.5\aboverulesep-0.5\belowrulesep-0.5\lightrulewidth}{%
  \textbf{Class 2}%
  }}
  \endgroup
    & C & a & b
\\\cmidrule{2-4}
    & D & c & d
\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]      [image: Variant Two]

Comment: Not what I was thinking. But it does look nicer