# How to make a Cayley table?

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make a Cayley table such as the one shown here http://dogschool.tripod.com/cayley.html

Thus this question doesn't help [Making an odd shaped table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62484/making-an-odd-shaped-table)

Comment: What exactly is your question though?, it seems to just be a standard table, filled with letters without any special typesetting requirement at all.

Comment: How would I represent that in latex?

Comment: as in the question you reference using `tabular` but without the `\multicolumn` and `\multirow` row spans which were the _odd shape_ in that question. see any example here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=tabular

Comment: My question is: why would you replicate such ugly tables? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you need is an example code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Your caption here}\label{tab:yourlabel}
\begin{tabular}{l|lll}
\toprule
\textbf{Hola1} & \textbf{Hola2} & \textbf{Hola3}\\
\midrule
datum1 & datum2 &datum3 &etc\\
datum4 & datum5 &datum6 &etc\\
%\midrule
datum7 & datum8 &datum9 &etc\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Your caption here}\label{tab:yourlabel}
\begin{tabular}{l|lll}
\toprule
\textbf{Hola1} & \textbf{Hola2} & \textbf{Hola3}\\
\hline
datum1 & datum2 &datum3 &etc\\
datum4 & datum5 &datum6 &etc\\
%\midrule
datum7 & datum8 &datum9 &etc\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Your caption here}\label{tab:yourlabel}
\begin{tabular}{l|lll}
\textbf{Hola1} & \textbf{Hola2} & \textbf{Hola3}\\
\hline
datum1 & datum2 &datum3 &etc\\
datum4 & datum5 &datum6 &etc\\
%\midrule
datum7 & datum8 &datum9 &etc\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3\\
    \hline
    4 & 5 & 6\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The results are:

[image]